# How does Qt handle label style with an invalid font family?

Tags: qt, internationalization, qlabel

I am currently extending a Qt application written for the United States for use in Korea and China.  I have used Qt Linguist with great success but some strings have lost all their styling.  Specifically, they have lost their weight and size.

If Qt tries to print a string with characters not supported in the font family, does it get the default style?

Comment: I'm currently trying to force font-size after accepting a style string but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  Does anybody know _when_ foreign characters cause a QLabel to take a default style?

Comment: Currently using a stylesheet to set pixel size, weight, and font-family.  All text can be rendered, but all the weight and sizing is lost.

Comment: As a work around, I have found that adding setting the application font to something with the appropriate writing system support works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best way to handle fonts in internationalized applications is to choose a font based on the chosen language as there are very few fonts with adequate character set coverage.